# How to see my scenario names in Test Result in Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, cucumber

In the Test Result section, the class names appear as classMethod. I use the cucumber test library for tests. In the Test Result section, I want to see the "Scenario:" names that I have specified in the feature file. What should I do about it? Can you help me?

build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.+'
testCompile("io.github.bonigarcia:webdrivermanager:3.+")
testCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-junit', version: '1.+'
compile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-java', version: '1.+'
testCompile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '1.7.25'
compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.25'
testCompile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '6.14.3'
}
```

RunFeature class:

```
package feature;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/java/testCases" )
public class RunFeatures {
}
```

Cucember feature:

```
Feature: OpenBrowser

Scenario: SelectBrowser
When I have opened "https://www.trendyol.com/" with "explorer" browser
```

Comment: Are you referring to the default html report where you would like to add scenario names?

Answer (score 0):

You can print the scenario name in the @before hook using the below code.

```
@Before
public void scenarioInit(Scenario scenario){
    String scenarioName = scenario.getName()
   //log the name to logger or to console here
}
```

you can log the name into your logger or into console.